# Adding Parent Keyword into existing keyword

Tags: web8, keyword

I have a keyword list that is getting quite large, is there an easy way to add a parent to an existing keyword so I can nest the keywords?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a parent to existing keyword, follow the steps given below in CME:

1. Create new parent keyword
2. Cut the existing keywords that you want to assign to new parent
3. Now go to parent keyword and paste the
   keyword

Hope this helps.

Comment: perfect! i didn't realize you could cut/paste the keywords, this should help immensely!